# What is the algorithm to factor something like $2+\frac{1}{x}+x?$

Tags: factoring

I came across this in homework but I'm interested in the general example, say $ax+bx^{-1}+c.$

Comment: What about factoring $ax^2+b+cx$, does this look more promising?

Comment: Remember that the general way of factorising is to find zeros. So if you equate $ax+bx^{-1} +c = 0$, then you can multiply with $x$ on both sides and obtain a polynomial, which this have been marked a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

In fact if you write it like $\frac 1 x ( x ^ 2 + 2 x + 1 )$, the problem is just factoring a polynomial.